# React-Redux clock dosen't update it's state in DOM

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm making clock which "SET_COUNT" is dispatched every second.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // persistor.purge();

    setInterval(() => {
      store.dispatch(setCounter(store.getState().counterReducer.cnt + 1));
      console.log(store.getState().counterReducer.cnt);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

And also counter is displayed.

```
    <div className="App">
      <p>{store.getState().counterReducer.cnt}</p>
    </div>
```

`cnt` is updated every second, but it is displayed only in console not in the DOM.

Any ideas?

[image: Edit redux-persist test]

Comment: Not sure but maybe helps if you take a look at how to use `useSelector()` and `useDispatch()` hooks from **react-redux**. I have a working GitHub repository about how to use them, feel free to check it out: https://github.com/norbitrial/react-redux-loading-data-example

Comment: I'd love to use hooks, but not this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a Counter (export it using connect).

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { setCounter } from "./rootReducer";
import store from "./store";

 useEffect(() => {
    // persistor.purge();

    setInterval(() => {
      store.dispatch(setCounter(store.getState().counterReducer.cnt + 1));
      console.log(store.getState().counterReducer.cnt);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { cnt: state.counterReducer.cnt };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Counter);
```

Then in your App import your Counter And Use a provider

```
import React from "react";
import store from "./store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Counter from "./Counter";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Counter />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-persist-test-c5mh9?file=/src/Counter.js

Comment: I wonder why should i  use connect() in this case? because I've seen it in many cases using redux without connect()

Comment: please provide me a link to one of that cases and then i've will explaine difference in detaile

Comment: I've searched react-redux code in github and found that there was misunderstanding about the react-redux and realize that react-redux notify store changes in Provider and you can get changed store only through Provider so you can get changed store from connect which is Consumer.

Comment: Yah, that is the point. So if your problem is resolved, mark as answer :)